# Eclipse is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: android, eclipse

Below message thrown by Eclipse console:

> [SDK Manager]
>   '"C:\Users\Upendra\DOWNLO~1\ADT-BU~1\sdk\tools\lib\find_java.exe" -s'
>   is not recognized as an internal or external command, [2014-01-03
>   10:52:03 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager] operable program or batch file.

This question is already posted I have tried the mentioned solutions but it not worked for me.

There is no spaces between the folder.
The path given in Environment variable : `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin`

Comment: Did you try opening the path C:\Users\Upendra\DOWNLO~1\ADT-BU~1\sdk\tools\lib\ and seeing if there is a file called find_java.exe?

Comment: Yes Kevin, I have checked there are two files with this name, One is find_java.bat and other is find_java.exe

Comment: Just define a variable in Environment Variables called JAVA_HOME that points to your JDK installed directory `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin` and you are good to go.